# Bisection Method - Some Cases

Tags: functions, roots, bisection

Now I have a working code for Bisection Method but there are some cases I want to handle

1- The boundaries of trial: Can we put a negative interval? ex. start with $f(-5)$ and end with $f(5)$ ?

2- If we start with zero and the function have $Ln()$ or $Log()$, that will give an error, Is there a special case to handle that ?

3- What if I have a function like $x^2-4 = 0$ which have 2 roots of $2$ & $-2$ , how can it be handled?

Comment: For (2) your programming language will have a standard way of catching such an error. Up to you what you do with the information - change the boundary value slightly towards where you know the root is? For (3) a "reasonable" approach might be to test the value of f(x) in your range over 100 values say and count the sign changes. The number of sign changes changes will be the number of roots in the range. Clunky and not foolproof. Finding multiple roots is tricky.

Answer (score 0):

You start with two values $x_1 < x_2$ which bracket  a zero, i.e. the function values $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ have opposite sign. And of course $f(x)$ must be     continuous  and defined on the interval $[x_1, x_2].$

$x_1=-5$ and $x_2=5$ are valid starting points, if the signs of the function values are opposite.

The requirement that is     continuous 
 is needed e.g. for $f(x)=-1, x<0, f(x)=1, x\ge0$ which has no zero but your process converges with $x_1 = -1, x_2=2.$

After your edit: It seems that your main problem is finding the starting values. There is no single universal method. Often the starting points are given by the
problem itself. A simple start is to look a plot of the function or a make table of $x, f(x).$

Regarding 3: Of course you can find both solutions. Again, look at a plot and see that one root is bracketed by $[-10,0]$ and other by $[0,10].$